# add a shortcut in Windows Git Bash (MinGW) for Visual Studio Code

Tags: windows, bash, visual-studio-code

I am looking for a way to add shortcuts in Windows Git Bash (MinGW).

```
$ code . // should open code in current location
```

The [Visual Studio Code setup page](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/setup) shows how to setup shortcuts in Mac OS X / Linux.

I just need a way to setup a basic shortcut so when I type

```
code c:\
```

it will execute:

> "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code.cmd" c:\

---

I got it to work using node:

```
node /c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Microsoft\ VS\ Code/bin/code.js .
```

Now I just need to make this into a shortcut.

I think this could be accomplished using a symlink. I'm just not sure how to add an extra variable in there i.e.

```
ln -s "node /c/path/to/code.js" code
```

Doing something like the above fails since adding a string is not recognized as valid path.

**solution**

to expand on zoon's answer the following worked for me

1. create a code.cmd file with the following contents

> ```
> #! /bin/sh
> node /c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Microsoft\ VS\ Code/bin/code.js $*
> ```

2. add a symlink to that code.cmd

   ln /c/path/to/file/code.cmd code

this allows me to pass path parameter to code

```
code ./somefolder/
```

Comment: Just to clatify the question: You are looking for a way to define a shortcut in Git Bash for Windows. You are **not** looking for a way to add a shortcut in Visual Studio Code, right?

Comment: correct! i'll update the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a shell script:

```
#! /bin/sh
cmd //C code.cmd $*
```

name it 'code' and put it with 'code.cmd'.